# Use of Hexadecimal colours in OpenGL

Tags: java, c++, opengl, lwjgl

I've got a theoretical question: Instead of using the standard RGBA colour model in OpenGL array buffers, why not just cut out 12 extra bytes per vertex and replace it with 1 integer that contains the colour in a hexadecimal format? Then in the shader you can convert that back into a vec4.

So what I mean is, replace this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(COL_INDEX, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, stride, offset);
```

To this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(COL_INDEX, 1, GL_INT, false, stride, offset);
```

I've tried to look everywhere online and I haven't found anything about this. Also, are there any performance benefits to saving those 12 bytes? Thanks for you time.

Comment: editing the question so that it partly invalidates an already given answer is at least a bit unfortunate...

Comment: @derhass I wasn't mean to do that? It was a mistake on my part that I didn't see until you said it as I was creating the question from memory. I don't want to confuse anyone else who might have this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, using `4*4` as size argument for `glVertexAttribPointer` is invalid. Valid sizes are 1 to 4, and 4 is exactly what you want here, as you need 4 channels to encode RGBA vectors.

The second version is not really useful. If we ignore the bogus `1*4` in the same way and use only one channel, it could work in principle, but `glVertexAttribPointer` cannot be used to set up integer attributes. What this would do is setting up a `float` attribute in the shader, while the data format is the buffer is `GL_INT`. You will lose some precision here, as you can't represent all 2^32 integer values exactly as 32bit floats, which will totally screw up the results.

You could use `glVertexAttribIPointer` (note the I in the middle) to set up an `int` attribute.

However, you don't need such a complex operation. All you need is

```
glVertexAttribPointer(COL_INDEX, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, stride, offset)
```

to use 4 separate bytes as a `vec4` attribute which is automatically normalized to the [0,1] range when accessed in the shader (this is the purpose of setting the `normalize` argument of this function to `GL_TRUE`).

Comment: Apologies. I was mistaken between the stride and size parameters - "1*4" and "4*4" shouldn't be there. I've now changed that. So 64 bit integers won't be valid? Will the same case be applied to setting the colour as a uniform?

Comment: I don't see what 64 bit integers have to do this. Actually, GLSL does not support such a type. There are some vendor-specific extensions. And uniforms are a completely different case.